# How can I add or remove a bookmark tag in Firefox via the command line?

Tags: database, sqlite, firefox, database-schema, bookmarks

I have been looking at the [places database](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/Database) and at the [Web Extension Bookmarks API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks) but I'm not sure how to do it or if it is possible.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer.  It got me interested but please don't forget that on SO  you should create -  How to create a Minimal Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that is not possible via the Web Extension Bookmarks API.  That is reserved and can be used only within an add-on.

To quote:

> JavaScript APIs for WebExtensions can be used inside the extension's
>   background scripts and in any other documents bundled with the
>   extension, including browser action or page action popups, sidebars,
>   options pages, or new tab pages. A few of these APIs can also be
>   accessed by an extension's content scripts (see the list in the
>   content script guide).
>
> To use the more powerful APIs you need to request permission in your
>   extension's manifest.json

I don't know if you are on windows or *nix.  The general idea would be to manipulate the SQLite database.

For bookmarks you need a file called [places.sqlite](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite) which you can find on windows at - `C:\Users\login\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles`

On *nix you can do:

`find . -name 'places.sqlite'` and usually you will get it somewhere in your home:

e.g.
`/home/tukanos/.mozilla/firefox/tf8oiuhk.default/places.sqlite`

### I'll cover only windows & powershell now (you can do that also for *nix):

I think it is also good idea to follow a [best practices guide](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Places/Places_SQL_queries_best_practices) for the `places.sqlfile`.  Be sure to read it before you start changing the file.

**NOTE**: make backup of your places.sqlite before playing with it!

In powershell you would

```
Import-Module pssqlite
```

(Download the module [here](http://download%20at%20https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSSQLite) if you are using PS version < 5.0)

Then get your path for `places.sqlite`

```
$db = 'C:\Users\login\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\tf8oiuhk.default\places.sqlite'
```

To query the sql database:

```
$sqlFirefoxQuery = "SELECT places.id, 
                           places.URL,
                           places.GUID,
                           bookmarks.title,
                           bookmarks.id,
                           bookmarks.parent
                      FROM moz_places as places
                      JOIN moz_bookmarks as bookmarks 
                        ON places.id = bookmarks.fk"


Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $db -QueryTimeout 20 -Query $sqlFirefoxQuery | Out-file -Encoding UTF8 Bookmarks_firefox.txt
```

The logic is the same for inserting, updating, deleting data.

Below you can find example of `insert` and `delete` as that was your question.

To insert data use sql `INSERT INTO`
 For example:

```
insert into moz_bookmarks (attributes) VALUES (your_values), (next_values)
```

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO moz_bookmarks (type, parent, title, dateAdded)  
     VALUES (1,5,'MyBookmark',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

To remove values you should use sql's `delete`:

```
DELETE FROM from moz_places
     WHERE id=1112
```

(don't forget to close your Firefox)

Use your database link - to find the attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/Database

### **Edit** - How to get a **tag** from sqlite DB?

To simply list all tabs in the bookmarks directory:

```
select * from moz_bookmarks where parent=4
```

**explanation:**
This will get you all the bookmarks stored in your places.sqlite file.  The tags are stored in the column `title` the TAGs folder has id=4

You can check the ID from in table `moz_bookmarks_roots`:

```
╔═══╦═════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║   ║ root_name       ║ folder_id     ║
╠═══╬═════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1 ║ places          ║   1           ║
║ 2 ║ menu            ║   2           ║
║ 3 ║ toolbar         ║   3           ║
║ 4 ║ tags            ║   4           ║
║ 5 ║ unfiled         ║   5           ║
╚═══╩═════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Now how to find a tag with certain bookmarks?

1. First find your bookmark which you want to work with
   e.g. title from this question "%How can I add or remove a bookmark tag%"

   ```
   SELECT * FROM moz_places where title LIKE '%How can I add or remove a bookmark tag%'
   ```

The result:

```
id              : 20079
url             : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51124179/how-can-i-add-or-remove-a-bookmark-tag-in-firefox-via-the-command-line/51264053?noredirect=1#
                  comment89523757_51264053
title           : How can I add or remove a bookmark tag in Firefox via the command line? - Stack Overflow
rev_host        : moc.wolfrevokcats.
visit_count     : 1
hidden          : 0
typed           : 0
favicon_id      : 238
frecency        : 125
last_visit_date : 1531301813682000
guid            : w6vYlxdKQU6V
foreign_count   : 2
url_hash        : 47357855952022
```

2. Then you go to `moz_bookmarks` table where you can find the actual records (`id` from `moz_places` is `fk` from `moz_bookmarks`).

   ```
   select * from moz_bookmarks where fk=20079
   ```

This result:

```
    id           : 76
    type         : 1
    fk           : 20079
    parent       : 75
    position     : 0
    title        : How can I add or remove a bookmark tag in Firefox via the command line? - Stack Overflow
    keyword_id   :
    folder_type  :
    dateAdded    : 1531298577890000
    lastModified : 1531298577894000
    guid         : R0961JLfZYKj

    id           : 78
    type         : 1
    fk           : 20079
    parent       : 77
    position     : 0
    title        :
    keyword_id   :
    folder_type  :
    dateAdded    : 1531298593884000
    lastModified : 1531298593884000
    guid         : BW__oMQbHerd
```

As you see you get two records.  One has `parent=75` which is the bookmark folder.  Second one is a mapping of `fk=20079` (`id`) to `parent=77` which are  the actual tag(s):

```
    SELECT * FROM moz_bookmarks where id = 77
```

Where you get the tags in the `title` attribute:

```
    id           : 77
    type         : 2
    fk           :
    parent       : 4
    position     : 0
    title        : stack_overflow test
    keyword_id   :
    folder_type  :
    dateAdded    : 1531298593878000
    lastModified : 1531298593884000
    guid         : AVcyFpGkrfzV
```

So the tags in my case were: `stack_overflow` `test`

The E-R schema for `places.sqlite` you can find [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/images/d/d5/Places.sqlite.schema3.pdf).

### **Edit 2** Forgot to answer the question directly.

When changing the sqlite database close *Firefox* instance.

To **add** a tag - you have to understand the logic (I have to pick a new bookmark which has no tags yet):

First to create I have to have a new bookmark

```
$sqlFirefoxQuery = "SELECT * FROM moz_places where title LIKE '%Cnn%'"

PS C:\> Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $db -QueryTimeout 20 -Query $sqlFirefoxQuery


id              : 20223
url             : https://edition.cnn.com/
title           : CNN International - Breaking News, US News, World News and Video
rev_host        : moc.nnc.noitide.
visit_count     : 1
hidden          : 0
typed           : 0
favicon_id      : 2015
frecency        : 75
last_visit_date : 1531392673997000
guid            : qqCRafq4FIcn
foreign_count   : 1
url_hash        : 47358730651511
```

Then I select from `moz_bookmarks` table:

```
$sqlFirefoxQuery = "select * from moz_bookmarks where fk=20223"
PS C:\> Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $db -QueryTimeout 20 -Query $sqlFirefoxQuery

id           : 79
type         : 1
fk           : 20223
parent       : 75
position     : 1
title        : CNN International - Breaking News, US News, World News and Video
keyword_id   :
folder_type  :
dateAdded    : 1531392718191000
lastModified : 1531392718197000
guid         : 2ywnKBmbDWJI
```

As you see there is only one record instead of two (check above the section where I select the `moz_bookmarks` and find two records)

You then have to find out a free `id`(s) at table `moz_bookmarks`.  In my case it is `id=80` and `id=81` (can be different in your case):

Now comes the tricky part where you have to get `GUID`.  You can get one via GUI - [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) and its `SELECT GENERATE_GUID()`.  However, we need one without gui so we have to create it.

If you check the gecko's python [makeGuid()](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/cf965b1f59ed4b3f7c736bc1b78cbb9e6975245c/third_party/python/gyp/pylib/gyp/MSVSNew.py) function you will see that they are using `md5`, `hex`.  I will do it with similar functions `hex()` and `randomblob()`.

First to generate the tag record:
Then the record itself (type=2, parent=4):

```
id           : 80
type         : 2
fk           :
parent       : 4
position     : 0
title        : news insert_firefox_tag_example
keyword_id   :
folder_type  :
dateAdded    : 1531298593878000
lastModified : 1531298593884000
guid         : <generated_GUID>
```

The actual insert:

```
$sqlFirefoxQuery = "INSERT INTO moz_bookmarks (id, type, parent, position, title, dateAdded, lastModified, guid)
     VALUES (80,
             2,
             4,
             0,
             'news insert_firefox_tag_example',
             strftime('%s',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)*1000000,
             strftime('%s',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)*1000000,
             hex(randomblob(2)) || hex(randomblob(2)) || hex(randomblob(2)))"
```

Then you have to create the record that links it:

```
    id          : 81
    type       : 1
    fk          : 20223
    parent       : 80
    position     : 0
    title        :
    keyword_id   :
    folder_type  :
    dateAdded    : 1531298593884000
    lastModified : 1531298593884000
    guid         : <generated_GUID>
```

The actual insert:

```
$sqlFirefoxQuery = "INSERT INTO moz_bookmarks (id, type, fk, parent, position, dateAdded, lastModified, guid)
     VALUES (81,
             1,
             20223,
             80,
             0,
             strftime('%s',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)*1000000,
             strftime('%s',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)*1000000,
             hex(randomblob(2)) || hex(randomblob(2)) || hex(randomblob(2)))"
```

Now you can check your record where you have added two new tags `news` `insert_firefox_tag_example`.

To **update** a tag with `new_tag` (you have to add the current tags too!):

```
$sqlFirefoxQuery = "UPDATE moz_bookmarks
                       SET title = 'stack_overflow test new_tag' 
                     WHERE id = 77"
```

Then execute it:

```
Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $db -QueryTimeout 20 -Query $sqlFirefoxQuery
```

You will get updated tags:

```
PS C:\> $sqlFirefoxQuery = "SELECT * FROM moz_bookmarks where id = 77"
PS C:\> Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $db -QueryTimeout 20 -Query $sqlFirefoxQuery


id           : 77
type         : 2
fk           :
parent       : 4
position     : 0
title        : stack_overflow test new_tag
keyword_id   :
folder_type  :
dateAdded    : 1531298593878000
lastModified : 1531298593884000
guid         : AVcyFpGkrfzV
```

To **remove** the tags you can do simply put an empty string (don't forget that the changes will be probably seen after Firefox restart):

```
$sqlFirefoxQuery = "UPDATE moz_bookmarks
                       SET title = '' 
                     WHERE id = 77"
```

The result:

```
PS C:\> $sqlFirefoxQuery = "SELECT * FROM moz_bookmarks where id = 77"
PS C:\> Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $db -QueryTimeout 20 -Query $sqlFirefoxQuery


id           : 77
type         : 2
fk           :
parent       : 4
position     : 0
title        :
keyword_id   :
folder_type  :
dateAdded    : 1531298593878000
lastModified : 1531298593884000
guid         : AVcyFpGkrfzV
```

So that is it.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that documentation for the database but I couldn't tell which field represented a tag or what I would need to insert to update them

Comment: @Andrew Ah, I see.  I'll edit the answer with tags representation.  It is not that straight forward.

Comment: @Andrew now I have added a way how to find the tags.  I have created an example and followed it.